# Job for snapd.seeded.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: 16.04, snap

apt-cache policy snapd
snapd:
  Installed: 2.32.9
  Candidate: 2.32.9
  Version table:
 *** 2.32.9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
chris@localhost:~$ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04

After updating snapd from 2.32.3.2 to 2.32.9 this morning I received the following error output:

```
Job for snapd.seeded.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status snapd.seeded.service" and "journalctl -xe"      
for details. snapd.seeded.service couldn't start.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
```

Output of "systemctl status snapd.seeded.service:

```
systemctl snapd.seeded.service
Unknown operation snapd.seeded.service.
chris@localhost:~$ systemctl status snapd.seeded.service
● snapd.seeded.service - Wait until snapd is fully seeded
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.seeded.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-06-01 07:58:40 CDT; 5min ago
Process: 15535 ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap wait system seed.loaded (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 15535 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Jun 01 07:58:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
Jun 01 07:58:40 localhost.localdomain snap[15535]: error: cannot communicate  with server: Get http://local
Jun 01 07:58:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Main process exited, code=exited, 
Jun 01 07:58:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
Jun 01 07:58:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 01 07:58:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Looking at journalctl -xe shows nothing, maybe I waited to long to run it? However this is syslog output for that time frame:

```
Jun  1 07:58:35 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
Jun  1 07:58:40 localhost snap[15535]: error: cannot communicate with server: Get http://localhost/v2/snaps/system/conf?keys=seed.loaded: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
Jun  1 07:58:40 localhost systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun  1 07:58:40 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
Jun  1 07:58:40 localhost systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun  1 07:58:40 localhost systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun  1 07:58:40 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon.
Jun  1 07:58:40 localhost systemd[1]: Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.
Jun  1 07:58:41 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Jun  1 07:58:41 localhost snapd[15552]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Jun  1 07:58:41 localhost snapd[15552]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Jun  1 07:58:42 localhost snapd[15552]: 2018/06/01 07:58:42.104321 daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.33~rc1 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/16.04 (amd64) linux/4.13.0-43-generic.
Jun  1 07:58:42 localhost systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
Jun  1 07:58:42 localhost systemd[1]: Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.
Jun  1 07:58:44 localhost kernel: [863229.980726] audit: type=1400 audit(1527857924.259:138): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=15577 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  1 07:58:44 localhost kernel: [863229.994170] audit: type=1400 audit(1527857924.272:139): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=15577 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  1 07:58:47 localhost snapd[15552]: 2018/06/01 07:58:47.766008 storehelpers.go:413: cannot refresh:
Jun  1 07:58:47 localhost snapd[15552]: snap "nethack": snap has no updates available
Jun  1 07:58:47 localhost snapd[15552]: snap "speed-test": snap has no updates available
Jun  1 07:58:47 localhost snapd[15552]: snap "snapweb": snap has no updates available
Jun  1 07:58:47 localhost snapd[15552]: snap "core": snap has no updates available
Jun  1 07:58:47 localhost snapd[15552]: snap "snappy-debug": snap has no updates available
Jun  1 07:58:47 localhost snapd[15552]: snap "wallpaperdownloader": snap has no updates available
Jun  1 07:58:47 localhost snapd[15552]: snap "pubip": snap has no updates available
Jun  1 07:58:47 localhost snapd[15552]: snap "dwarf-fortress": snap has no updates available
Jun  1 07:58:47 localhost snapd[15552]: 2018/06/01 07:58:47.770673 autorefresh.go:338: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
```

Snapd is running:

```
systemctl status snapd
● snapd.service - Snappy daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-06-01 07:58:42 CDT; 53min ago
Main PID: 15552 (snapd)
CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
       └─15552 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

Jun 01 07:58:47 localhost.localdomain snapd[15552]: 2018/06/01 07:58:47.766008 storehelpers.go:413: cannot refresh:
Jun 01 07:58:47 localhost.localdomain snapd[15552]: snap "nethack": snap has no updates available
Jun 01 07:58:47 localhost.localdomain snapd[15552]: snap "speed-test": snap has no updates available
Jun 01 07:58:47 localhost.localdomain snapd[15552]: snap "snapweb": snap has no updates available
Jun 01 07:58:47 localhost.localdomain snapd[15552]: snap "core": snap has no updates available
Jun 01 07:58:47 localhost.localdomain snapd[15552]: snap "snappy-debug": snap has no updates available
Jun 01 07:58:47 localhost.localdomain snapd[15552]: snap "wallpaperdownloader": snap has no updates available
Jun 01 07:58:47 localhost.localdomain snapd[15552]: snap "pubip": snap has no updates available
Jun 01 07:58:47 localhost.localdomain snapd[15552]: snap "dwarf-fortress": snap has no updates available
Jun 01 07:58:47 localhost.localdomain snapd[15552]: 2018/06/01 07:58:47.770673 autorefresh.go:338: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
```

Question is just what does "snapd.seeded.service" do and why did it fail? Does it affect the running of snaps?

Answer (score 6):

You can fix the issue with this command:

```
$ sudo snap install hello-world
```

Start `snapd.seeded.service` again:

```
$ systemctl start snapd.seeded.service
```

Verify if `snapd.seeded.service` is running:

```
$ systemctl status snapd.seeded.service
```

This question on AskUbuntu might be helpful: [snapd.seeded.service couldn't start on upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042671/snapd-seeded-service-couldnt-start-on-upgrade)

Comment: It works in Arch also.