# snapd.seeded.service couldn't start on upgrade

Tags: snap

Any hints about how to resolve below? Not sure what the implications are of this or if it will impact system performance. I've included the output from `systemctl status snapd.seeded.service` below the output from the `apt-get upgrade`. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

output from `apt-get upgrade`;

```
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 snapd 
amd64 2.32.9 [13.5 MB]
Fetched 13.5 MB in 8s (1,513 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 1020256 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.32.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.32.9) over (2.32.3.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up snapd (2.32.9) ...
Job for snapd.seeded.service failed because the control process exited with 
error code. See "systemctl status snapd.seeded.service" and "journalctl -xe" 
for details.
snapd.seeded.service couldn't start.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it
```

Here's the output from `systemctl status snapd.seeded.service`

```
snapd.seeded.service - Wait until snapd is fully seeded
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.seeded.service; enabled; vendor 
pre
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-06-01 07:54:12 CDT; 1h 
58mi
Process: 23187 ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap wait system seed.loaded (code=exited, 
s
Main PID: 23187 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 01 07:54:07 dennis-OptiPlex-780 systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is 
ful
Jun 01 07:54:12 dennis-OptiPlex-780 snap[23187]: error: cannot communicate 
with 
Jun 01 07:54:12 dennis-OptiPlex-780 systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Main 
proce
Jun 01 07:54:12 dennis-OptiPlex-780 systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait until 
snapd
Jun 01 07:54:12 dennis-OptiPlex-780 systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Unit 
enter
Jun 01 07:54:12 dennis-OptiPlex-780 systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Failed 
wit
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try running `sudo snap install hello-world` and see if that installs the Snap Core. After doing that mine seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks, it installed the snap core, but didn't resolve the problem. I am going to have to look into snaps more. snap list shows the core, and hello-world are the only two snaps installed on my system, after running sudo snap install hello-world, which leads me to believe neither were installed when snapd upgrade issue happened. I am guessing snapd refers to a daemon, but I don't know. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this today, but managed to fix the problem by rebooting via typing `systemctl reboot` into the terminal.